# How can I display SVG correctly in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, svg, polyfills

The tile configurator on my website (cas.berfect.de/2.php) creates tile patterns using SVGs. Everything is displayed correctly on all common browsers. But it doesn't work in Internet Explorer.

I noticed that IE does not understand tags like "Symbol" and "Use". Therefore I made use of the Polyfill library "svgforeverybody.js". It converts "Symbol" elements to "Rect" elements, but the Shadow DOM is still missing. How can I make my application work in Internet Explorer?

Here is the code:

```
  <defs class="">

    <symbol id="tile" onclick="holstClick(this, 'select');" class="">
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="tile_90" class="">
      <use href="#tile" x="0" y="0" transform="rotate(90, 70.85, 70.85)" class=""></use>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="tile_90_r" class="">
      <use href="#tile" x="0" y="0" transform="translate(141.7, 0) scale(-1 1) rotate(90, 70.85, 70.85)" class=""></use>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="tile_180" class="">
      <use href="#tile" x="0" y="0" transform="rotate(180, 70.85, 70.85)" class=""></use>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="tile_r" class="">
      <use href="#tile" x="0" y="0" transform="translate(141.7, 0) scale(-1 1)" class=""></use>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="tile_180_r" class="">
      <use href="#tile_r" x="0" y="0" transform="rotate(180, 70.85, 70.85)" class=""></use>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="tile_270" class="">
      <use href="#tile" x="0" y="0" transform="rotate(270, 70.85, 70.85)" class=""></use>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="tile_270_r" class="">
      <use href="#tile" x="0" y="0" transform="translate(141.7, 0) scale(-1 1) rotate(270, 70.85, 70.85)" class=""></use>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="tile-block" width="290" height="290" class="">
      <use href="#tile_r" x="145" y="0" class=""></use>
      <use href="#tile" x="0" y="0" class=""></use>
      <use href="#tile_180" x="145" y="145" class=""></use>
      <use href="#tile_180_r" x="0" y="145" class=""></use>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="tile-line" class="">
      <use href="#tile-block" x="2610" y="0" class=""></use>
      <use href="#tile-block" x="2320" y="0" class=""></use>
      <use href="#tile-block" x="2030" y="0" class=""></use>
      <use href="#tile-block" x="1740" y="0" class=""></use>
      <use href="#tile-block" x="1450" y="0" class=""></use>
      <use href="#tile-block" x="1160" y="0" class=""></use>
      <use href="#tile-block" x="870" y="0" class=""></use>
      <use href="#tile-block" x="580" y="0" class=""></use>
      <use href="#tile-block" x="290" y="0" class=""></use>
      <use href="#tile-block" x="0" y="0" class=""></use>


    </symbol>
    <symbol id="layer-0" class="">
      <use href="#tile-line" x="0" y="2610" class=""></use>
      <use href="#tile-line" x="0" y="2320" class=""></use>
      <use href="#tile-line" x="0" y="2030" class=""></use>
      <use href="#tile-line" x="0" y="1740" class=""></use>
      <use href="#tile-line" x="0" y="1450" class=""></use>
      <use href="#tile-line" x="0" y="1160" class=""></use>
      <use href="#tile-line" x="0" y="870" class=""></use>
      <use href="#tile-line" x="0" y="580" class=""></use>
      <use href="#tile-line" x="0" y="290" class=""></use>
      <use href="#tile-line" x="0" y="0" class=""></use>
    </symbol>

    <symbol id="border" onclick="holstClick(this, 'select');" class=""></symbol>

    <symbol id="border_r_rt" class="">
      <use href="#border" x="0" y="0" transform="translate(141.7, 0) rotate(180 145 71)" class=""></use>
    </symbol>

    <symbol id="border_r_rt_flip" class="">
      <use href="#border" x="0" y="0" transform="translate(0, 0) rotate(0 145 71)" class=""></use>
    </symbol>

    <symbol id="border_r" class="">
      <use href="#border" x="0" y="0" transform="translate(141.7, 0) scale(-1 1)" class=""></use>
    </symbol>

    <symbol id="border_r_object" class="">
      <use href="#border_r_rt" x="0" y="0" class=""></use>
    </symbol>

    <symbol id="border_2_tile" class="">
      <use href="#border" x="0" y="0" class=""></use>
      <use href="#border_r_object" x="145" y="0" class=""></use>
    </symbol>

    <symbol id="border_2_tile_hr" class="">
      <use href="#border_r_object" x="0" y="0" class=""></use>
      <use href="#border" x="145" y="0" class=""></use>
    </symbol>

    <symbol id="border_2_tile_hr_2" class="">
      <use href="#border_r_object" x="0" y="0" class=""></use>
      <use href="#border" x="145" y="0" class=""></use>
      <use href="#border" x="0" y="0" transform="translate(141.7, 0) rotate(45 145 71)" class=""></use>
    </symbol>

    <symbol id="border_line_2_tile" class="">
      <use href="#border_2_tile" x="0" y="0" class=""></use>
    </symbol>


    <symbol id="border_line" class="">
      <use href="#border_line_2_tile" x="2610" y="0" class=""></use>
      <use href="#border_line_2_tile" x="2320" y="0" class=""></use>
      <use href="#border_line_2_tile" x="2030" y="0" class=""></use>
      <use href="#border_line_2_tile" x="1740" y="0" class=""></use>
      <use href="#border_line_2_tile" x="1450" y="0" class=""></use>
      <use href="#border_line_2_tile" x="1160" y="0" class=""></use>
      <use href="#border_line_2_tile" x="870" y="0" class=""></use>
      <use href="#border_line_2_tile" x="580" y="0" class=""></use>
      <use href="#border_line_2_tile" x="290" y="0" class=""></use>
      <use href="#border_line_2_tile" x="0" y="0" class=""></use>
    </symbol>

    <symbol id="border_line_90" class="">
      <use href="#border_line" x="0" y="0" transform="rotate(90, 143, -1.5)" class=""></use>
    </symbol>

    <symbol id="border_line_180" class="">
      <use href="#border_line" x="2612" y="-143" transform="rotate(180, 2610, 0)" class=""></use>
    </symbol>

    <symbol id="border_line_270" class="">
      <use href="#border_line" x="-2610" y="-145" transform="rotate(270, 143, -1.5)" class=""></use>
    </symbol>

    <symbol id="border_4line" class="">
      <use href="#border_line" x="0" y="725" class=""></use>
      <use href="#border_line_270" x="290" y="0" class=""></use>
      <use href="#border_line_90" x="2465" y="0" class=""></use>
      <use href="#border_line_180" x="0" y="2030" class=""></use>
    </symbol>

    <symbol id="border_4line_vr" class="">
      <use href="#border_line" x="0" y="2030" class=""></use>
      <use href="#border_line_270" x="2465" y="0" class=""></use>
      <use href="#border_line_90" x="290" y="0" class=""></use>
      <use href="#border_line_180" x="290" y="725" class=""></use>
    </symbol>

    <symbol id="layer-border" class="">
      <use href="#border_4line_vr" x="0" y="0" class=""></use>
    </symbol>




    <symbol id="border_angle" class=""></symbol>
    <symbol id="border_angle_180" class="">
      <use href="#border_angle" x="0" y="0" transform="rotate(180, 70.85, 70.85)" class=""></use>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="border_angle_90" class="">
      <use href="#border_angle" x="0" y="0" transform="rotate(90, 70.85, 70.85)" class=""></use>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="border_angle_270" class="">
      <use href="#border_angle" x="0" y="0" transform="rotate(270, 70.85, 70.85)" class=""></use>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="layer_border_angle" class="">
      <use href="#border_angle_180" x="290" y="725" class=""></use>
      <use href="#border_angle_270" x="2465" y="725" class=""></use>
      <use href="#border_angle" x="2465" y="2030" class=""></use>
      <use href="#border_angle_90" x="290" y="2030" class=""></use>
    </symbol>








    <symbol id="over_border_line" onclick="holstClick(this, 'select');" class="">
      <rect fill="#FFF" width="145" height="145" class=""></rect>
      <rect fill="#FFF" width="145" height="145" x="145" class=""></rect>
      <rect fill="#FFF" width="145" height="145" x="290" class=""></rect>
      <rect fill="#FFF" width="145" height="145" x="435" class=""></rect>
      <rect fill="#FFF" width="145" height="145" x="580" class=""></rect>
      <rect fill="#FFF" width="145" height="145" x="725" class=""></rect>
      <rect fill="#FFF" width="145" height="145" x="870" class=""></rect>
      <rect fill="#FFF" width="145" height="145" x="1015" class=""></rect>
      <rect fill="#FFF" width="145" height="145" x="1160" class=""></rect>
      <rect fill="#FFF" width="145" height="145" x="1305" class=""></rect>
      <rect fill="#FFF" width="145" height="145" x="1450" class=""></rect>
      <rect fill="#FFF" width="145" height="145" x="1595" class=""></rect>
      <rect fill="#FFF" width="145" height="145" x="1740" class=""></rect>
      <rect fill="#FFF" width="145" height="145" x="1885" class=""></rect>
      <rect fill="#FFF" width="145" height="145" x="2030" class=""></rect>
      <rect fill="#FFF" width="145" height="145" x="2175" class=""></rect>
      <rect fill="#FFF" width="145" height="145" x="2320" class=""></rect>
      <rect fill="#FFF" width="145" height="145" x="2465" class=""></rect>
    </symbol>


    <symbol id="over_border_line_90" class="">
      <use href="#over_border_line" x="0" y="0" transform="rotate(90, 143, -1.5)" class=""></use>
    </symbol>




    <symbol id="layer_over_border" class="">
      <use href="#over_border_line_90" x="146" y="0" class=""></use>
      <use href="#over_border_line_90" x="2610" y="0" class=""></use>
      <use href="#over_border_line" x="0" y="577" class=""></use>
      <use href="#over_border_line" x="0" y="2175" class=""></use>
    </symbol>





  </defs>

  <use href="#layer-0" x="0" y="0" width="100000" height="100000" class=""></use>
  <use href="#layer-border" x="0" y="0" width="100000" height="100000" class=""></use>
  <use href="#layer_border_angle" x="0" y="0" width="100000" height="100000" class=""></use>
  <use href="#layer_over_border" x="0" y="0" width="100000" height="100000" class=""></use>
  </svg>
```

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] and add it to the question please?

Comment: I have created a web page to test your code, the result is a blank page in Chrome, Microsoft Edge and IE browser, please post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Which IE browser version are you using? the defs and symbol support IE 9+. You could check [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/symbol).

Comment: I expect IE would require xlink:href rather than just href.